# join between two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Let I have two tables say A and B. Both are related via a primary key field say C. Now, I just want to grab all data from only table A have but not in B using join concept. Literary I want A-B in term of sets.

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: a simple sql tutorial should be enough ..  try google for this

Comment: Hint: left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sample of left join

```
SELECT a.*
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.C = a.C
WHERE b.C IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from A
where A.c not in (Select B.c from B)
```